# How to override an automatically generated method using "nswag"?

Tags: typescript, swagger, aspnetboilerplate, nswag

I've reported a bug recently in the [**nswag**](https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/697) library when using object as a property in a DTO class.

Till they fix it, is there any workaround or a way to override the generated code in the proxy service?

Comment: you can edit the liquid template.
Should be the template found at https://github.com/RSuter/NJsonSchema/blob/master/src/NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.TypeScript/Templates/Class.liquid